# Text under icon, flexbox

Tags: flexbox

I want my text to center under my icons but won't get my flexbow to work.
Right now the text is horizontal on the right side of the icon, but I want it to be underneath.

[image]

Here is my code.

HTML:

```
<section class="portfolio-section-green">
    <div class="project-card" href="#">
      <h4>FOR MORE</h4>
      
      <div class="for-more-wrapper">
        <a class="for-more-icon" href ="https://www.linkedin.com/in/johanna-rexin-56207144/">
          <img src="./images/linkedin.svg" alt="linkedin" />
        </a>
        <p class="for-more-name">LINKEDIN</p>
      
      
        <a class ="for-more-icon" href ="https://github.com/johannarexin">
          <img src="./images/github.svg" alt="github" />
        </a>
        <p class="for-more-name">GITHUB</p>
      
      
        <a class="for-more-icon" href ="https://stackoverflow.com/c/technigo/users/144/?tab=profile">
          <img src="./images/stack_overflow.svg" alt="stack overflow" />
        </a>
        <p class="for-more-name">STACK OVERFLOW</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

CSS:

```
.for-more-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  }

.for-more-icon {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  }

.for-more-name {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you haven't specified the `align-items: center`.

When you have normal flex layout (without the column as the direction), then you use `justify-content: center`, for horizontally centered alignment.

But when you use the `flex-direction: column`, you are changing the whole flow of the layout, so the `justify-content` works for vertical alignment and `align-items` property works for horizontal alignment.

Here's a small demo:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/square/square_PNG19.png" width="50px" height="50px" />
  <span>Some text</span>
</div>
```

For your code, I have made some modifications to your code:

```css
.for-more-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
    gap: 7px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

.for-more-icon {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.for-more-links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section class="portfolio-section-green">
    <div class="project-card" href="#">
        <h4>FOR MORE</h4>

        <div class="for-more-links">
            <div class="for-more-wrapper">
                <a href ="https://www.linkedin.com/in/johanna-rexin-56207144/">
                    <img class="for-more-icon" src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/square/square_PNG19.png" alt="linkedin" />
                </a>
                <p class="for-more-name">LINKEDIN</p>
            </div>
            <div class="for-more-wrapper">
                <a href="https://github.com/johannarexin">
                    <img class="for-more-icon" src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/square/square_PNG19.png" alt="github" />
                </a>
                <p class="for-more-name">GITHUB</p>
            </div>
            <div class="for-more-wrapper">
                <a class="for-more-icon" href ="https://stackoverflow.com/c/technigo/users/144/?tab=profile">
                    <img class="for-more-icon" src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/square/square_PNG19.png" alt="stack overflow" />
                </a>
                <p class="for-more-name">STACK OVERFLOW</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you @Prathamesh :) I'm not sure on which classes to add the different code. I've tried as you did but it doesn't work. Any idea how to write it?

Comment: @JohannaRexin I have updated the code, please check

Comment: I think I was explaining poorly in my first question. I have added a picture of how I want the icons and text to look like. I would be really thankful if you could look at it and see if you know how to do it :) @Prathamesh

Comment: @JohannaRexin Okay got it, check the updated code